# Returning from anonymous function passed as parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, anonymous-function

Consider the following code:

```
function dbTask(q) {
    mysql = new MySQL();
    mysql.host = sqlHost;
    mysql.user = sqlUser;
    mysql.password = sqlPassword;
    mysql.query("USE stock");

    return mysql.query(q, function(err, results, fields) {
        if(err) {
            console.log("MySQL Error: " + err + ", Query: " + q);
            return false;
        } else {
            return results; //here
        }
    });
};

var r = dbTask("SELECT * FROM user;");
console.log(r);
```

Whereas, I want the `results` to be returned from the inner anonymous function when calling `dbTask()` in the second last line, I am getting different output which seems like some internal construct of the mysql library under use.

How can I get dbTask to return the `results` when called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `mysql.query` is asynchronous, then you'll have to re-think your architecture.

Instead of having your function return true or false, you'll have to *pass in* handlers to be called if the query returned true or false.

Something like this:

```
function dbTask(q, success, failure) {
    mysql = new MySQL();
    mysql.host = sqlHost;
    mysql.user = sqlUser;
    mysql.password = sqlPassword;
    mysql.query("USE stock");

    mysql.query(q, function(err, results, fields) {
        if(err) {
            console.log("MySQL Error: " + err + ", Query: " + q);
            failure(err, results, fields);
        } else {
            success(results, fields);
        }
    });
};
```

Which you'd call like this:

```
dbTask(q, 
          function(results, fields) { /* ... */ }, 
          function(err, results, fields) { /* ... */ });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't because `dbTask` returns once the `mysql.query` call completes to initiate the query.  So by the time `mysql.query`'s callback is called, `console.log(r)` has already executed.

This is the crux of the asynchronous nature of node.js.

What you *can* do is have `dbTask` accept a callback parameter that the function calls once `results` is available so that it can be provided to the caller asynchronously.